# Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this? I'm actually trying to search null values in table and if possible suggest me an effective way to do it

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_MALEEMPLOYEES(@GENDER NVARCHAR(4))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
IF (@GENDER='NULL')
(SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, CASE WHEN MIDDLENAME IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE ' ' +MIDDLENAME+' ' END,LASTNAME) 
AS FULLNAME, CAST(BIRTHDATE AS DATE) AS BIRTHDATE,GENDER FROM PERSON.PERSON
A INNER JOIN [Sales].[vPersonDemographics] B ON A.BUSINESSENTITYID = B.BUSINESSENTITYID 
WHERE GENDER IS NULL)
ELSE
(SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, CASE WHEN MIDDLENAME IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE ' ' +MIDDLENAME+' ' END,LASTNAME) 
AS FULLNAME, CAST(BIRTHDATE AS DATE) AS BIRTHDATE,GENDER FROM PERSON.PERSON
A INNER JOIN [Sales].[vPersonDemographics] B ON A.BUSINESSENTITYID = B.BUSINESSENTITYID 
WHERE GENDER =@GENDER)
```

Comment: How come you compare your variable with `='NULL'` on your IF, and `IS NULL` on your WHERE?

Comment: No - no one can tell you what is "wrong with this" without knowing how it is used and what "wrong" means. The others have made assumptions about your code. Perhaps you intended to pass the string 'NULL' as a parameter; others have assumed the opposite. But no one really knows without a better definition of the problem. It is a bit odd that you use both the concat function and the contenation operator - inconsistency is a bad developer habit. Equally, a function that has a very specific name but a generic function is not a good sign.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's just i've been trying to solve it for hours and couldn't thatswhy

Answer (score 0):

Null cannot equal null. You have to use IS NULL as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_MALEEMPLOYEES(@GENDER NVARCHAR(4))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
IF (@GENDER IS NULL)
(SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, CASE WHEN MIDDLENAME IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE ' ' +MIDDLENAME+' ' END,LASTNAME) 
AS FULLNAME, CAST(BIRTHDATE AS DATE) AS BIRTHDATE,GENDER FROM PERSON.PERSON
A INNER JOIN [Sales].[vPersonDemographics] B ON A.BUSINESSENTITYID = B.BUSINESSENTITYID 
WHERE GENDER IS NULL)
ELSE
(SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, CASE WHEN MIDDLENAME IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE ' ' +MIDDLENAME+' ' END,LASTNAME) 
AS FULLNAME, CAST(BIRTHDATE AS DATE) AS BIRTHDATE,GENDER FROM PERSON.PERSON
A INNER JOIN [Sales].[vPersonDemographics] B ON A.BUSINESSENTITYID = B.BUSINESSENTITYID 
WHERE GENDER =@GENDER)
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing against `NULL` you use `IS NULL`, not `='NULL'` as this last one is the varchar literal.

You can also make your function easier and more maintainable like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_MALEEMPLOYEES(@GENDER NVARCHAR(4))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
SELECT 
    CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, CASE WHEN MIDDLENAME IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE ' ' +MIDDLENAME+' ' END,LASTNAME) AS FULLNAME, 
    CAST(BIRTHDATE AS DATE) AS BIRTHDATE,
    GENDER 
FROM 
    PERSON.PERSON A 
    INNER JOIN [Sales].[vPersonDemographics] B ON A.BUSINESSENTITYID = B.BUSINESSENTITYID 
WHERE 
    ISNULL(GENDER, '') = ISNULL(@GENDER, '')
```